# Is it possible to clone an ES6 promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to create a generic "retry" function that accepts a promise object and plays the promise back a certain number of times before eventually resolving or rejecting.

I've already written a piece of code that accepts an array of promises and works through them sequentially until 1 succeeds or they all fail.

```js
var first = function(promiseArr){
    return promiseArr.reduce(function (prev, next) {
        return prev.catch(()=>next)
    });
};

first([Promise.reject("1"), Promise.resolve("2"), Promise.reject("3")])
.then(function(data){
    console.log('resolved with '+data);
}, function(err){
    console.log('rejected with '+err);
});
```

I'm now trying to write a function which accepts a promise and populates an array with size N with deep copy clones of the promise. I've managed to make it work with vanilla objects, but I can't seem to make it work with promise objects.

I realize I could just accept an executing function and build the promises myself, but I would like to be able to reuse my already promisified functions in the project.

```js
var retry = function(promise, maxCount){
    return first(Array(maxCount).fill(function(){
        //return a deep copy of the promise passed in
    })
  }
```

Comment: Think of promise as a "future value". Value, not a function. You can't replay a value. To implement retry you'll need something more "powerfull"  either a function (that creates a promise) or say Observables.

Comment: Might there be a way to pull the executing function off a promise passed in and use it in the construction of others?

Answer (score 3):

Your approach of creating "deep clones" of a promise, whatever that is supposed to mean, and playing through them, is flawed. The paradigm for retrying a promise is nothing more complicated than

```
function foo() {
  return doSomething().catch(foo);
}
```

Then you add logic for number of retries:

```
function retry(n) {
  return function foo() {
    if (!n--) return Promise.reject("max retries exceeded");
    return doSomething.catch(foo);
  }();
}
```

Comment: I realize you can recurse the executing function to chain promises onto itself, but my issue is that i'm receiving the promises sight unseen and I need to be able to make a generic one do what you've described. If there was a way I could determine the executing function in order to pack it into a catch statement, that would be enough to solve my problem.

Comment: You can't. The executor is a hidden detail of the construction of the promise.

Comment: If you are handed a created promise from outside, as opposed to a function to create it (such as `doSomething` above), then your options are severely limited; you can hang `then` and `catch` off it but there's no way to "replay" or "recreate" or "clone" it.